# How to Access DOM inside HTML object in GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt

How can I access DOM inside an HTML object which is fetched via RequestBuilder? Following is a shortened code regarding my question:

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(
    RequestBuilder.POST, 
    "/experiment.txt");

requestBuilder.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
            HTML responseHTML = new HTML(response.getText());
            //TODO parse responseHTML
        } 
    }

    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {}
});
```

Suppose that, following is the contents of `responseHTML`:

```
HTML responseHTML=new HTML(
    "<div id='div_1'>my div 1</div>" + 
    "<div id='div_2'>my div 2</div>");
```

Is it possible to get `div_1` from inside `responseHTML` in such a way like:

```
responseHTML.getElementById("div_1");
```

Comment: is your response going to be always the same? Like presented list of div's? or would it be very generic, returning different many times nested elements?

Comment: Yes, it is going have the same DOM hierarchy for this scenario.

Comment: I have updated my answer, maybe using GQuery would be good solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you attach your `responseHTML` to the DOM, you can use [Dom.getElementById(String id)](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29.)

If you haven't attached the `responseHTML` to the DOM, you can try to use the  [GQuery  framework](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) to select/find needed `DOM` elements. Simple example would be:

```
// select div with id=div_1 from responseLabel element
GQuery divWithIdQuery = GQuery.$("div#div_1", responseLabel);

// assuming that only one div was selected you can get its content :
String div1HTML = divWithIdQuery.toString();

// You can get the Element as well
Element div1Element = divWithIdQuery.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;


    Element elementById = DOM.getElementById("div_1");
```

now use  `elementById`

Make sure that I have been already added to the DOM before you are getting.

Comment: Suresh, HTML object is not within Document object. It is the response of a RequestBuilder. I am adding some more details to the question.

Comment: @Halil Nope I guess :) then you need to use some String parsing or regex solution for that based up on that ID. What you are getting from response ? a String ?